# How to zero-fill first column of data

Tags: perl, unix, multiple-columns

I have data like this in tab separated columns:

```
1   name1   attribute1
1   name1   attribute2
1   name1   attribute3
31  name2   attribute1
31  name2   attribute2
31  name2   attribute3
444 name3   attribute1
444 name3   attribute2
444 name3   attribute3
```

And I want to have it like this:

```
001 name1   attribute1
001 name1   attribute2
001 name1   attribute3
031 name2   attribute1
031 name2   attribute2
031 name2   attribute3
444 name3   attribute1
444 name3   attribute2
444 name3   attribute3
```

Can I do this in unix or perl for instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -i~ -pe's/^(\d+)/sprintf "%03d", $1/e' file
```

Actually, the above checks more than it needs to. Here's a more general solution:

```
perl -i~ -pe's/^([^\t]*)/sprintf "%03s", $1/e' file
```

Comment: Drop the `~` if you don't want to make backup. Drop `-i~` entirely if you don't want to override the original file.

Comment: @ikegami.. Can you please provide an explanation of the above code??

Comment: -i~ - modify file in place, leave copy of original as filename~
-p  - automatically loop over lines of file and print them out
-e  - code to run in between reading and writing each line, with current line in $_ variable
s/old/new/ - replace old with new in $_
^(\d+) - match one or more digits at beginning of line
/e = treat replacement part of s// as perl code to run to produce replacement instead of literal string
sprintf "%03d", $1 - take part of string that matched first set of parentheses and format it as a 3-digit number with leading zeroes

Comment: Thanks so much @MarkReed.. That was a nice explanation.. As you explained, I remembered that I actually read about that, and have actually forgotten everything.. Need to practice more..  :) :)

Comment: `perl -i~ -pe's/^(\d+)\s+/sprintf "%03d ", $1/e' file` more accurately fulfils the requirement

Comment: @Borodin, it's a tab-separated file. You can actually clobber entire columns with that code. Added a more generic solution to my answer.

Comment: Yes I missed the part about it being tab-separated

Answer (score 1):

The Awk and Perl answers are both great.  I would also add that in Perl, if you don't know ahead of time how many digits you are going to have in the first column, you can replace the "3" in "%03d" part with a scalar value that contains the length of your longest number in the first column.

Comment: Or `sprintf '%0*d', $max_width, $num`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{ $1 = sprintf ("%03d", $1) }1' file.txt
```